# C, why header files inclusion is not needed on .c files?

Tags: c, header, include, c99, defined

in C language in order to prevent multiple inclusion of a header file we write:

```
#if !defined(PROJECT_MODULE_H)
#define PROJECT_MODULE_H

... all header file contents go here ...

#endif
```

But why don't we write the same to prevent multiple inclusion of .c files as well?

Comment: Because a header file might `#include` other header files, and there can be circular referencing too. But .c files do not (usually) `#include` other .c files.

Comment: And including .c files is a **very bad practice**. More practical when using an IDE that automatically add directory .c files in the project (i.e. Eclipse) the file will be compiled 2 times inside the one that includes it and as standalone directly from IDE.